# area legend and fillbetween

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I would simply like to change the legend entries from being lines to a green rectangle for the first entry of the legend and a green rectangle for the second: I am using `pgfplot` and `fillbetween`, I want the same legend output as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348433/add-a-legend-entry-describing-the-area-of-a-fill-plot), but with the same trick does not work in my case (maybe I didn't understand something)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=9cm,compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title = {$\delta = 0.9$},
xlabel = {$\xi$},
ylabel = {$c(\xi)$},
xmin = 0,
xmax = 1,
ymin = 0.17,
ymax=  1,
legend pos = south east,
]
\addplot[
name path = A,
domain= 0:1,
samples= 100,
line width = 1.2 pt, 
]
{(1+x)/2};
\node at (axis cs:  .8,  .84){\footnotesize$C(\xi)$};
\addplot[
name path  = B,
domain= 0:1,
samples= 100,
style = dashed,
]
{(1/4 + (0.9 +x)/2};
\node at (axis cs: 0.2,0.87){\footnotesize$\bar{c}(\xi;\delta)$};
\addplot[
name path = C,
domain= 0:1,
samples= 100,
style = dashed,]
{(3/4 + (-0.9 +x)/2};
\node at (axis cs:  .8,  .63){\footnotesize$\underline{c}(\xi;\delta)$};
\addplot[fill=green, fill opacity = 0.3, draw = none,area legend] fill between [of = A and C, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
\addlegendentry{$Q_{ABS} < Q_{S,PC}$};
\addplot[fill=red, fill opacity = 0.3, draw = none,area legend] fill between [of = B and A, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
\addlegendentry{$Q_{ABS} > Q_{U,PC}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:SustProf}
\caption{Some Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code using  `\addlegendimage{area legend, ...}` to put the rectangles in the legend area.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=9cm,compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                title = {$\delta = 0.9$},
                xlabel = {$\xi$},
                ylabel = {$c(\xi)$},
                xmin = 0,
                xmax = 1,
                ymin = 0.17,
                ymax=  1,
                legend pos = south east,    
                ]
                \addlegendimage{area legend, fill=green, fill opacity = 0.3}                  
                \addlegendimage{area legend, fill=red, fill opacity = 0.3}
                \addplot[
                name path = A,
                domain= 0:1,
                samples= 100,
                line width = 1.2 pt, 
                ]
                {(1+x)/2};
                \node at (axis cs:  .8,  .84){\footnotesize$C(\xi)$};
                \addplot[
                name path  = B,
                domain= 0:1,
                samples= 100,
                style = dashed,
                ]
                {(1/4 + (0.9 +x)/2};
                \node at (axis cs: 0.2,0.87){\footnotesize$\bar{c}(\xi;\delta)$};
                \addplot[
                name path = C,
                domain= 0:1,
                samples= 100,
                style = dashed,]
                {(3/4 + (-0.9 +x)/2};
                \node at (axis cs:  .8,  .63){\footnotesize$\underline{c}(\xi;\delta)$};
                
                \addplot[fill=green, fill opacity = 0.3, draw = none] fill between [of = A and C, soft clip={domain=0:1}];

                \addplot[fill=red, fill opacity = 0.3, draw = none] fill between [of = B and A, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
                
                \addlegendentry{$Q_{ABS} < Q_{S,PC}$};                  
                \addlegendentry{$Q_{ABS} > Q_{S,PC}$};

            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{fig:SustProf}
        \caption{Some Caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The code could be easier to read using

```
...
                legend pos = south east,
                legend entries={$Q_{ABS} < Q_{S,PC}$,   $Q_{ABS} > Q_{S,PC}$},          
                ]
                \addlegendimage{area legend, fill=green}                  
                \addlegendimage{area legend, fill=red}

....
```

instead of `\addlegendentry`

Answer (score 4):

Every `\addlegendentry` command adds an entry to the legend starting from the first `\addplot` command. It is irrelevant where you place the `\addlegendentry` command (it must be added after the relevant `\addplot` command, of course). Thus, with your code you add two legend entries that refer to the first and the second `\addplot` command respectively and not to the last two. Since you did not provide the option `area legend` to the first two `\addplot` commands (which is totally correct, because you don't want to add a legend entry for these plots anyways), you will get (dashed or thick) lines as legend picture.

You can verify this behaviour by adding some more `\addlegendentry` commands to your code. You will see that the legend pictures will have the same styling as the respective `\addplot` macros:

[image]

So, what you essentially need to do is to skip the first three `\addplot` commands so that legend entries will only be added for the last two `\addplot` commands. You can use the option `forget plot` to achieve this (see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14507/47927)).

Having added the option `forget plot` to the first three `\addplot` commands, the correct legend images will magically appear:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=9cm, compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title = {$\delta = 0.9$},
xlabel = {$\xi$},
ylabel = {$c(\xi)$},
xmin = 0,
xmax = 1,
ymin = 0.17,
ymax=  1,
legend pos = south east,
]
\addplot[
name path = A,
domain= 0:1,
samples= 100,
line width = 1.2 pt, 
forget plot
]
{(1+x)/2};
\node at (axis cs:  .8,  .84){\footnotesize$C(\xi)$};
\addplot[
name path  = B,
domain= 0:1,
samples= 100,
style = dashed,
forget plot
]
{(1/4 + (0.9 +x)/2};
\node at (axis cs: 0.2,0.87){\footnotesize$\bar{c}(\xi;\delta)$};
\addplot[
name path = C,
domain= 0:1,
samples= 100,
style = dashed,
forget plot
]
{(3/4 + (-0.9 +x)/2};
\node at (axis cs:  .8,  .63){\footnotesize$\underline{c}(\xi;\delta)$};
\addplot[fill=green, fill opacity = 0.3, draw = none, area legend] fill between [of = A and C, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
\addplot[fill=red, fill opacity = 0.3, draw = none, area legend] fill between [of = B and A, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
\addlegendentry{$Q_{ABS} < Q_{S,PC}$}
\addlegendentry{$Q_{ABS} > Q_{U,PC}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:SustProf}
\caption{Some Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In certain cases, `forget plot` might lead to unwanted side effects, because it does not only remove the plot from the legend. You can also put empty legend entries instead using `\legend{,,,$Q_{ABS} < Q_{S,PC}$,$Q_{ABS} > Q_{U,PC}$};`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=9cm, compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title = {$\delta = 0.9$},
xlabel = {$\xi$},
ylabel = {$c(\xi)$},
xmin = 0,
xmax = 1,
ymin = 0.17,
ymax=  1,
legend pos = south east,
]
\addplot[
name path = A,
domain= 0:1,
samples= 100,
line width = 1.2 pt, 
]
{(1+x)/2};
\node at (axis cs:  .8,  .84){\footnotesize$C(\xi)$};
\addplot[
name path  = B,
domain= 0:1,
samples= 100,
style = dashed,
]
{(1/4 + (0.9 +x)/2};
\node at (axis cs: 0.2,0.87){\footnotesize$\bar{c}(\xi;\delta)$};
\addplot[
name path = C,
domain= 0:1,
samples= 100,
style = dashed,
]
{(3/4 + (-0.9 +x)/2};
\node at (axis cs:  .8,  .63){\footnotesize$\underline{c}(\xi;\delta)$};
\addplot[fill=green, fill opacity = 0.3, draw = none, area legend] fill between [of = A and C, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
\addplot[fill=red, fill opacity = 0.3, draw = none, area legend] fill between [of = B and A, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
\legend{,,,$Q_{ABS} < Q_{S,PC}$,$Q_{ABS} > Q_{U,PC}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:SustProf}
\caption{Some Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above.